# Start docker container under non-root user

Tags: docker, ssh, dockerfile

my dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y git openssh-server \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN groupadd --gid 3000 jenkins \
    && useradd --uid 3000 --gid jenkins --shell /bin/bash --create-home jenkins
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

EXPOSE 22


ENTRYPOINT /usr/sbin/sshd -D && bash
```

```
docker build --tag sample .
```

i tried to start it with jenkins user

```
docker run -u 3000:3000 sample
```

which returns

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

i've read all similar questions on stackoverflow and nothing works in my case.

was tried

```
RUN yes 'y' | ssh-keygen -b 1024 -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/all_needed_keys  -N ''
```

also doesn't work

```
RUN /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A
```